# Spring 3.x and hibernate 4.x transaction management issue using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I'm using Spring 3.0 and hibernate 4.x, but I'm facing issue on transaction management. I'm using @Transactional annotation in service layer but it is taking too long time to save large amount of data into Database.

here is my transaction manager:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And I'm using this line of code to insert data:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(deal);
```

Please if anybody has the solution, help me out.

Comment: is there insert or update operation?

Comment: In general solution is bulk insert:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718305/batch-insertions-with-hibernate-spring

Comment: I'm inserting data into Database.

Comment: Could you paste your transaction manager and connection pool configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Transactional` is not responsible for your performance.
first of all use ***Batch Processing*** for large amount of data as follows

```
int i = 0;
for(Deal deal : deals)
    session.save(deal);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
   i++; 
}
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

read more about Chapter [***13. Batch processing***](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

Sometimes it is not the query itself which causes a slowdown - another query operating on the table can easily inserts to slow down due to transactional isolation and locking.
read more about this external factores

[link1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21935/slow-insert-performance-in-mysql-innodb-table-for-solr-indexing)

***[innodb_buffer_pool_size=614M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827308/insertion-speed-slowdown-as-the-table-grows-in-mysql)***

***[too many indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120160/mysql-too-many-indexes)***

***[Primary Key Genration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026968/high-performance-hibernate-insert)***

***[Why is MySQL InnoDB insert so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819271/why-is-mysql-innodb-insert-so-slow)***

hope this things will help you out